# Uneven intervals with setInterval function due to other code running between intervals;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am trying to have a div do a simple slide into a parent div in a React project using pure JS and am having problems with the smoothness of the slide. When I console log, I can see that when the code (slideIn) runs, between setInterval calls, React runs other code which take up more time than the specified intervals. Therefore, the intervals are not even, which seems to be causing the jerkiness in the slide.

I have tried requestAnimationFrame also, but the result is the same.

The challenge seems to be to make the slideIn continuous without having react run other code while running it, but how does one do that?

```
 <div className="outer-box">
    <div className="sliding-box"></div>
 </div>

  .outer-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .sliding-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }

  slideIn() {
    const moveElemment = document.getElementById('sliding-box');
    const pos = -100;
    if (moveElemment) {
      const id = setInterval(frame, 10);
      function frame() {
        if (pos == 0) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          pos++;
          moveElemment.setAttribute('style', `left: ${pos}%`);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not use a native API, ie `window.scroll` or similar to scroll it?

Comment: Rather use a CSS transition if it's just for a simple slide left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perphas you could take advantage of CSS transitions to achieve smoother animation that is decoupled from the JS thread, to resolve your problem? For example, you could update your CSS with a `transition` rule and additional selector as follows:

```
.sliding-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100px; // Initial position of sliding-box
    transition: left 1s linear; //Specify the animation behaviour
}
.sliding-box.in {
    left: 0px; // Position of sliding-box after animation
}
```

with simplified JS to trigger the transition animation as follows:

```
slideIn() {
    const moveElemment = document.getElementById('sliding-box');
    if (moveElemment) {
      // When this selector is added, it triggers the animation
      // transition from left:-100px to left:0px over a 1 second 
      // interval
      moveElemment.classList.add('in'); 
    }
  }
```